# Selenium crawler automate next button for 100+ pages using Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, iterator, web-crawler, click

I'm crawling a page for all the ID's (3000+) which i'm later saving into a text file.

So my code is working the way i want it to, but now i'm searching for an automated method instead of repeating the below process 100+ times, clicking through the webpage.
Something like:

```
next.click()*100.....
```

Constructive advice is greatly appreciated :)

My current (working) code:

```
next = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'img.down')
#next page button

main = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.id")
time.sleep(2)
for m in main:
    print(m.text)

next.click()

time.sleep(2)
main = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.id")

for m in main:
    print (m.text)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: I would use infinite while loop in this case, can you give more context? before clicking to next button what you are doing ? also to click on next button, you can just do `next.click()` why do you have `main = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.id")
time.sleep(2)
for m in main:
    print(m.text)` loop after the next web element ?

Comment: @cruisepandey thanks for responding.
Well, every page i'm crawling the ID's from images, hereafter i click next via `next.click()` and repeat the process. But since there are 100+ pages == 100+ `next.click()` methods it's a bit of a hassle. So i'm looking for a way to get around that. Hope this clarifies it a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tip!
A while loop using WebDriverWait does the trick.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
while True:
        main = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.id")
        time.sleep(2)
        for m in main:
            print(m.text)
        try:
                element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img.down')))
                element.click()
        except TimeoutException:
                break

driver.quit()
```